# PostgreSQL Partial Indexing for Reservations Web App (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, indexing

Looking for some insights into a potential indexing issue.

I'm working on a Ruby on Rails hostel reservations app.

Reservation model looks like this:

```
business_id int
client_name text
bed_id int
check_in_time datetime
check_out_time datetime
finished boolean, default: false
notes text
```

When a person checks in for their reservation and gets their key `check_in_time` is set. When they leave the hostel and give back their key, `check_out_time` is set and `finished` is set to `true`.

Most hostels have 25-100 FINISHED IS FALSE reservations. These are the reservations (clients) actively on the property. Some businesses are getting to have 30,000+ FINISHED IS TRUE reservations in their entire database. These are reservations from the past eight years.

Right now, the only index is `index_reservations_on_business_id`

For a few hostels, when they visit their main reservations page, it takes 5+ seconds to load their active (FINISHED IS FALSE) reservations, since it pulls up all their reservations using the business_id index, but then it has to find only those that are FINISHED IS FALSE (when 90% are FINISHED IS TRUE).

I've read that adding indexes on booleans isn't smart, since there are only two options. However, like I said, 90% of reservations are completed (FINISHED IS TRUE) and don't need to show up on the active reservations page.

Would adding a partial index like below make sense?

`index reservations on finished is false`

This way, the DB would first pull up the business's reservations (using the business_id index), and then quickly find just those that are NOT finished (using the partial index).

Thoughts? Suggestions? Any help is appreciated.

EDIT:
I'm a relatively new developer. Is there a way to test an index without launching it in production? Production DB has over 3 million reservations, whereas development only has several thousand, so even in development, PG doesn't use any indexes since the dataset is so small.

Here's an `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` Sometimes it takes 5+ seconds for hostels with lots of old reseravations.

```
Sort  (cost=50099.98..50100.67 rows=275 width=67) (actual time=521.299..521.310 rows=21 loops=1)
  Sort Key: client_name
  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 27kB
    ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on reservations  (cost=691.63..50088.84 rows=275 width=67) (actual time=519.035..519.814 rows=21 loops=1)
        Recheck Cond: (business_id = 1234)
        Filter: (NOT finished)
        Rows Removed by Filter: 37324
        Heap Blocks: exact=16056
        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_reservations_on_business_id  (cost=0.00..691.56 rows=37218 width=0) (actual time=30.928..30.928 rows=37345 loops=1)
              Index Cond: (business_id = 1234)

Planning time: 0.425 ms
Execution time: 521.413 ms
```

Comment: that depends on the queries you got, but byou cann add multiple indexes with dieffrent combined coumns and test them. As rule columns that are in the `WHERE` and `ON` clause in a combined index

Comment: Offtopic: I would change the two columns check_in_time and check_out_time to a single column, using a timestamp range, tsrange. That is so much more powerful, especially in combination with constraints to avoid double bookings. See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html

Comment: The syntax you show for the partial index is not valid syntax for creating a partial index, nor is it obvious how to turn it into a valid syntax.  Maybe `CREATE INDEX on  reservations (business_id) where (not finished)`?

Comment: As for testing larger data sets -- having a staging or QA environment with a comparable database is a solid approach. A one off solution is restoring a copy of the production database to a local env -- not recommended for sensitive data -- and testing the DB changes there.